# how to make my searchBar TableView perform a segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have created a TableView application following the "Beginning iPhone Development with Swift " book.The search Bar tableView is created with code and not within the storyboard.The book explains how to get search results and display the corresponding cells but I would like my app to perform a segue to a ViewController I have created in the storyBoard.How can I trigger a Segue with code ?

for more info , this is my file :

```
import UIKit


class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController , UISearchResultsUpdating{

let sectionsTableIdentifier = "section identifier"
var products = [product]()
var filteredProducts = [product]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: sectionsTableIdentifier)
}


// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredProducts.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
    sectionsTableIdentifier) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = filteredProducts[indexPath.row].name
    return cell }




// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailView"{
        let index = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var destinationViewController : infoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as infoViewController

        destinationViewController.Title  = filteredProducts[index!.row].title
        destinationViewController.eam  = filteredProducts[index!.row].energy
        destinationViewController.fam  = filteredProducts[index!.row].fat
        destinationViewController.pam  = filteredProducts[index!.row].protein
        destinationViewController.cam  = filteredProducts[index!.row].carbohydrates
        destinationViewController.imgName  = filteredProducts[index!.row].imgName

    }

}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(
    searchController: UISearchController) {
let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
filteredProducts.removeAll()
        for prod in products{
            var name = prod.name.lowercaseString
            if name.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil {
                filteredProducts.append(prod)
            }
        }
 tableView.reloadData()
}}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is the SearchResultsController instance itself created in code, or just the tableView?

Comment: the SearchResultsController is also created in code, in an other class :     `let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
            resultsController.products = self.produits
            searchController =     UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        searchBar.placeholder = "Enter a food name"
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController`

Answer (score 0):

Because the controller is built in code, you need to use the `SearchResultsController`'s tableView delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to trigger the presentation of the next view controller.

Assuming that there is a table view controller underpinning the `SearchResultsController`, you could potentially use that as the delegate of the `SearchResultsController`.  The main table view controller might already have the necessary code to segue when a cell is selected, in which case you need to check which tableView has been selected in order to correctly determine which product the cell represents.

To set the delegate, add the following line to the code (in your comment above) where you create the `SearchResultsController`:

```
resultsController.tableView?.delegate = self
```

Then amend the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to test which tableView is triggering the method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        // use the existing code to present the detail VC, based on the data in the main table view
        ...
    } else {
        // use new code to present the detail VC, based on data from the SearchResultsController
        ...
    }
}
```

If the main table view controller is in a storyboard, you can use a segue to present the detail VC.  In this case you would use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier()` in the above code.  If not, you would either use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController()` (if you are embedded in a navigation controller) or `self.presentViewController()` (to present the detail VC modally).

Another option would be to set the `SearchResultsController`'s `delegate` to be `self` (in `viewDidLoad`), and then to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the `SearchResultsController` class.  In this case, you don't need to test which tableView has triggered the method, but you will not be able to use a segue.

Comment: I tried your method ,what happens is that when I type a keyword in my searchBar and the filtered cells appear when I click on one of those cells nothing happens and when I push the cancel button of the searchBar I end up on the detailView .So basically it's like the segue is done in the background and there is not an apparent segue it's done in the background and you can see the detailView only once you cancelled the research.I hope you will understand.

Comment: I understand your description, though I can't immediately explain it.  Have you tried the option in my final paragraph - setting the SearchResultController's tableView delegate to self, and implementing didSelectRowAtIndexPath in that class?

Comment: Having tested a little, one workaround (in my original solution) is to change the `active` property of the UISearchController after undertaking the segue - add `searchController.active = false` at the end of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I performed your method with the pusviewController method , and it's working fine but since i created the view controller on the storyboard ( I think it's the reason ) my view controller appears black.I think I have to make the targeted view controller also in code and not with the storyboard . I also think I will switch to objective c because , men with this version of swift we're not able to create a decent tableview application without using some tricks. Tell me what you think about my idea

Comment: By the way I tried the self.performSegueWithIdentifier method and it works fine . Now I jut need to know how to access the filteredProduct list of my search class from my main tableview class so I can transmit the value of the corresponding row to the targeted view Controller

Comment: I don't think I have really understood how to use UISearchController properly.  I note that the Apple docs for it say "This is a preliminary document for an API or technology in development."  So perhaps Apple will iron out some of its wrinkles in future releases.  I'm not sure objective-c will be any better than Swift (though personally I am more familiar with obj-c).  Hope you are able to get it working.